# Cannot deploy astro project

Tags: node.js, astrojs

I recently created an astro (+ react) project, and when I try running it on my server with `node apps/server/entry.mjs` I get this error:

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@astrojs/internal-helpers' imported from /home/xxx/apps/server/entry.mjs
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:890:9)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:939:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1132:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:835:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:77:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

Locally I have the same node version (`v18.18.0`) and the same command works fine.
My astro version is `3.6.4`.

```
Astro                    v3.6.4
Node                     v18.18.0
System                   macOS (arm64)
Package Manager          npm
Output                   server
Adapter                  @astrojs/node
Integrations             @astrojs/solid-js
                         @astrojs/react
                         @astrojs/svelte
```

Comment: I don't trust beta packages because you will receive this error afterward.

Comment: @Κωλζαρ what beta package? the project folder is called beta but that's about it. I'm using `"astro": "^3.6.4"`

Comment: This `@astrojs/internal-helpers` package.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the answer from their discord channel. It's a pretty silly mistake, but I assumed wrongly that the deployment in `standalone` mode was self contained.

What's needed for deployment is not only to sync the dist folder with the remote server, but also the `package*.json` files, then run `npm install` from the remote folder with those `package*json`, then run `node [...]/entry.mjs`.